# What is the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^{-2} e^{-x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

In my research, I reached to the
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\! \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}x^2}e^{-x^2/2}\, dx.
$$

I have tried polar change of systems, integral by parts and change of variables but I did not reach to any solution. I plotted the integrand and I see that it is very near to Dirac delta function. However, I did not found is it equal to it or not?

Comment: The integral diverges due to the behaviour for small $x$.

Comment: the dirac delta 'function' is not strictly a function, the shape of this function may be close but it cannot be equal to it

Comment: What is the context for this integral appearing? Is it something physical?

Answer (score 2):

The integral does not converge, in fact near $x=0$ the function behaves like $1/x^2$ and it's well known that
$$\int_0^1\frac1{x^p}\mathrm dx <+\infty \iff p<1$$

Answer (score 1):

Noticing that the integrand is positive and
$$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx =2 \int _{0}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx = 2\left[\int _{0}^{1} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx + \int _{1}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx \right]> 2\int _{0}^{1} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx. $$

For any $a>0,$ $$\int _{0}^{1} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx > \int _{0}^{1} x^{-2}e^{-a} dx >+\infty,$$
Therefore $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-ax^2} dx$ is divergent for any $a>0$ and hence $\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{-2}e^{-x^2} dx$ is divergent too.